# Conditional validation if checkbox selected laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have a form in Laravel in which I want to validate three text fields based on a checkbox. Its an edit user form in which I only want to update the password if I select yes. This is the form in my view:

```
<section>
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Edit: {!! $user->name !!}</h1>
        {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['AccountController@update', $user->id], 'files' => true]) !!}
        <p>Name: {!! Form::text('name') !!}
        <p>Email: {!! Form::text('email') !!}
        <p>Update Password? (tick for yes) &nbsp; {!! Form::checkbox('updatepasswordcheck', 0, false) !!}
        <p>Old Password: {!! Form::password('oldpassword') !!} 
        <p>New Password: {!! Form::password('newpassword') !!}
        <p>New Password Confirm: {!! Form::password('newpasswordconfirm') !!}
        @if($user->role_id == 1) 
            <p>User Role: {!! Form::select('user_type', ['admin', 'guest'], '1') !!}
        @else
            <p> User Role: {!! Form::select('user_type', ['admin', 'guest'], '0') !!}
        @endif
        <p>{!! Form::submit('Update') !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        @include ('errors.list_errors')
    </div>
</section>
```

I then have a request called EditAccountRequest like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class EditAccountRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
      

        if($this->inputs['updatepasswordcheck'])
        {
            $rules['oldpassword'] = 'required';
            $rules['newpassword'] = 'required';
            $rules['newpasswordconfirm'] = 'required';  
        }
        $rules['name'] = 'required|min:3';
        $rules['email'] = 'required|email';
        
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I see if the checkbox 'updatepasswordcheck' is true it never works because the input always appears as null. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I worked it out. I did this and it works:

```
public function rules()
{
        if($this->has('updatepasswordcheck'))
        {
            $rules['oldpassword'] = 'required';
            $rules['newpassword'] = 'required';
            $rules['newpasswordconfirm'] = 'required';  
        }
        $rules['name'] = 'required|min:3';
        $rules['email'] = 'required|email';

        return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and this code works fine, my scenario was if "Company Info" drop-down selected "Yes" then "Company Name" should be required.

Controller:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
   return Validator::make($data, [

      'company_name' => 'required_if:is_company,1',

   ]);
}
```

View:

```
<label class="control-label">Company Info</label>
<select id="is_company" class="form-control" name="is_company">
       <option value="0">No</option>
       <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>


<label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name">
```

[More Detail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: How if we use checkbox not dropdown?

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following in this example:

```
public function rules(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('updatepasswordcheck'))
    {
        $rules['oldpassword'] = 'required';
        $rules['newpassword'] = 'required';
        $rules['newpasswordconfirm'] = 'required';  
    }
    $rules['name'] = 'required|min:3';
    $rules['email'] = 'required|email';

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this and I got this error: Target [App\Http\Requests\Request] is not instantiable.

Comment: You need to have the following above your class and below the namespace,  `use App\Http\Requests\Request;`.

Comment: No that still gives an error because you are inside the request object or something

Comment: Just use `Request::has()` if the other doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner and straight forward solution

```
    $validated = $request->validate([
        .
        .
        .
        'newpasswordconfirm' => 'required|accepted',
        'oldpassword' => 'required',
        'newpassword' => $request->newpasswordconfirm === 'yes' ? 'required': 'nullable',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

may be can use required_unless for this purpose:

```
$this->validate($request, 
        [
            'content' => 'required_unless:otherfields,null',
        ],
        [
            'content.required_unless' => 'Please enter content for detail'
        ]);
```

Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-unless

there is another way to Take a look at the sometimes rule. This will run the rule only when the field is available:

Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules